# Cambio de estilo de boton en android

Tags: android

Hola soy nuevo en Android y estoy tratando de cambiar el estilo por defecto para ese boton, pero al momento de colocar un **android:background="@drawable/borde_redondo"** no me reconoce y me deja el estilo por defecto, estoy usando android 8.1 si alguien puede ayudar estaría agradecido.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]En tu carpeta drawable crea un XML con el siguiente contenido:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<solid android:color="#9E9E9E"/>
<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="100dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="100dp"
    android:topRightRadius="100dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#BDBDBD"/>
```

Posiblemente el código que has escrito no es el correcto para crear un botón circular.

Comment: si el xml asi, y me funciona con un AppCompatButton pero con un Button no funciona se queda por defecto el tema

Comment: Prueba utilizando un `NoActionBar` en la actividad donde asignas el botón

Comment: disculpa la pregunta pero en donde se cambia eso? estoy empezando y aun no tengo claro algunas cosas, muchas gracias

Comment: En la respuesta te dejo la imagen donde lo puedes cambiar, si no me equivoco eso solucionaría tu problema ya que la pantalla asigna estilos y colores por defecto a un activity.

Comment: Muchas gracias si funciono, en la previsualizacion, pero cuando lo compilo y lo ejecuto en un emulador o en un telefono se observa el tema por defecto y no los cambios que yo hice con el drawable.